# Drupal 8.2.5 no internal pages on fresh install

Tags: theming, 8, installation

Just installed Drupal 8 on a Ubuntu 16.04 server.   Everything looked great until the final install and then there was no stylesheets on the site and all of the links give an

```
The requested URL /admin was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server  ###########.net Port 80
```

error.  This error persists for all linked pages.

I installed it previously on the server with the same issue, except before it had the Bartik theme.   I realized I had built the database on it incorrectly and it was faster to reimage the server then go in and delete everything and put things back proper, plus I figured that way it would be fresh.

Thanks in advance for the help, 
Joey

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear caches using drush from the terminal.

```
drush cr
```

Also uncheck the following under **Bandwidth optimization**

External resources can be optimized automatically, which can reduce both the size and number of requests made to your website.

Aggregate CSS files

Aggregate JavaScript files

from 
http://drupal.local/admin/config/development/performance

Comment: I assume you mean drush in the drupal framework?

Comment: drush dr :  drush command to clear cache in drupal8,executed from terminal.